# how to provide functionality for cut,copy,paste,undo,redo,delete buttons in an web based application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i am creating a web based application where i created buttons for cut,copy,paste,undo,redo,delete options.I wanted to make all these buttons to work according to their functionality after clicking the button how can i implement that in my application? I am using html for my design and JavaScript and JQuery for Functionality.[image]

application screen shot

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iframe and set iframe.document.designMode = "On"; using javascript.

then use iframe.document.execCommand(aCommandName,aShowDefaultUI,aValueArgument);

find out more here [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)